Replace 1950's entry door weatherstripping
Our 1950's slab ranch has aluminum metal L-channel around the top and sides of the door frame. On the hinge side one side of the L fits into a kerf into the door. On the top and other side, there is a two-step rabbet cut in the door filled with a nailed-on piece of flat aluminum edging. Together these make a weatherstripping seal.
The L-channel aluminum is something like 1/32" thick, but folded on one side of the L. Each side of the L is about 5/8". The flat edging nailed to the door rabbet is just folded in half, making it 3/4" wide.
The aluminum metal strips are cracking, with missing pieces. I have searched for replacement product like this, but can't find anything preformed with even close to these dimensions.
I'm not sure what to call this kind of bent and folded aluminum  channel and strip. It could be "flashing", or "weatherstripping", or something else. Is this an obsolete product, or I am just not searching for it right?
The alternative is to replace the whole door, frame, etc. But there's nothing wrong with the door that some paint won't fix.



Try looking for bronze weatherstripping, not aluminium.

Oh, great! Thank you very much! I searched for bronze and also see zinc, and I see some similar products. I'll bet it's zinc, but either will work for me.
